# Scala ByteArrayInputStream to String

Tags: string, scala, apache-httpclient-4.x, scalatra, bytearrayinputstream

I'm trying to log the body of a post made using org.apache.http.client. I'm using Scalatra version 2.4.0.RC3 and Scala version 2.11.7. My response is a 400 Bad Request and I need to get the message provided in the response body.

Here is my current code:

```
val response = client.execute(post)
println(response)
println(response.getEntity().getContent())
```

response.getEntity().getContent() prints:

```
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@1q232e4e
```

I need to get the actual body as string from this ByteArrayInputStream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EntityUtils` form the same library:

```
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
```